# Curves in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Find a continuous bijective function so that an equation holds.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves

Problem:

Let $p,q \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\gamma: [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ ($a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$) a rectifiable curve with $\gamma(a) = p$ and $\gamma(b) = q$, which on no subinterval of $[a,b]$, that has positive length, is it constant.

Show that:

Let $L(\gamma) = |{p-q}|$ then there exists a continuous, bijective function $\delta:[a,b] \to [0,1]$ so that $$\gamma(t) = p + \delta(t)(q-p)$$ holds for all $t \in [a,b]$.

How do you prove this ? Proof ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $$\delta(t)=\dfrac{t-a}{b-a},$$ for which one gets
$$\delta^{-1}(s)=(b-a)s+a,$$
that can be deduced by solving $t$ from $s=\dfrac{t-a}{b-a}$.

Comment: Then your $\gamma$ is $$\gamma(t)=p+\dfrac{t-a}{b-a}(q-p).$$

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but how does this prove anything about $\gamma$? After all, your $\delta$ has nothing to do with $\gamma$.

Comment: it makes $\delta$ explicit, with the bijectivity implicit because it has inverse

Comment: But OP was asking for a way to find a $\delta$ for a given $\gamma$. You've given a $\delta$ with no relation to the given $\gamma$. You haven't used the fact that $\gamma$ is continuous or rectifiable or nonconstant on positive length intervals or has length $|p-q|$. You've just given an example of some homeomorphism $[a, b] \longrightarrow [0, 1]$. I suppose @MarkLauer did accept your answer, but as best as I can tell you did not answer their question.